# How can I make my microphone work on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: microphone, audio, cable

I can't get my dynamic microphone to work on my MacBook Pro. How do I go about it?

I have a speaker, headphone splitter and a 3.5 mm male-to-female audio cable.

Still, I cannot recognize the microphone on the MacBook.
Any suggestion ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The pinouts are completely wrong [even the visible number of bands don't match]. See [CableChick - Understanding TRRS and Audio Jacks](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/) for some grounding in the subject. You'll need the manual for the mic to know what that very odd plug is supposed to do. Is it meant to be stereo [or even less likely, balanced line]?

Comment: @Tetsujin, Yes it is supposed to be a stereo jack for the mic.

Comment: I can see it's a 'stereo' jack, TRS… that doesn't actually explain its function, which is why I asked.